# Support for Unhandled Exceptions - Client Side

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, visual-studio

While debugging the console application I'm currently building, I'm receiving the following error.

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException was unhandled
>
> Message=The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
> For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults
> (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration
> behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn
> on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the
> server trace logs.

We're operating on the client side in this situation, and the server side won't allow us to open up the error messaging to the web service so that we can get something a little more descriptive that the generic “The server was unable to process the request doe to an internal error” message. They "can’t do this on our servers because it is a security violation and goes against our server hardening."

Are there any other options that can be utilized on our side to better expand on this error message? Everything I've been able to find so far pertains to adjustments on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know. The whole point of hiding error messages from your client is to make sure he doesnt learn more about what goes wrong server side so he has avenues to exploit (security hole). Your options are to look in the event log of the server, exception logging on the server, catching and sending a valid error response to the client from the server and giving up.. Sorry I don't have better news... :(